# linq parsing ints from ArrayList

Tags: c#

I have an ArrayList that comes from a json deserializer. This array should only contain numbers but as always, bad things can happen and I'm looking to avoid having to handle an exception. This is what I have:

```
var TheListOfLongs = (from object s in TheArrayList 
                      select Convert.ToInt64(s)).ToList<long>();
```

This works fine as long as TheArrayList only contains numbers. How can I change the `Convert.ToInt64` statement to a `TryParse`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long outValue;
//will work, but double conversion
var result = TheArrayList.Cast<object>()
            .Where(m => Int64.TryParse(m.ToString(), out outValue))
            .Select(m => Convert.ToInt64(m)).ToList();

//should avoid double Parse, but untested, see Daniel Hilgarth's answer and warnings.
var result = TheArrayList.Cast<object>()
            .Where(m => Int64.TryParse(m.ToString(), out outValue))
            .Select(m => outValue).ToList();
```

or good old foreach, which is probably the best choice.

```
var list = new List<long>();
long outValue;
foreach (object value in the ArayList) {
   if (Int64.TryParse(value.ToString(), out outValue))
      list.Add(outValue);
}
```

Comment: Especially as this would double-convert, wouldn't it?

Comment: You _could_ avoid the double conversion by `Select`ing `m => outValue` instead, but that'll raise a few WTFs.

Comment: I don't think you should promote this without any warning words. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730400/572644) for details about the problems with this method.

Comment: I think you're right; the goodall foreach loop will do better. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @frenchie: That's the correct decision. If you have a lot of those conversions you can create an extension method for this task to not have to repeat that code all over the place.

Comment: Actually, I had to replace "var value" with "object value" and then in the if statement I changed to "if (Int64.TryParse((string)value, out...)" You might want to edit your answer.

Comment: @frenchie oh damn, my good old... was hell old buggy, indeed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
      Int64 value;
      var TheListOfLongs = TheArrayList.
                          Where(entry => Int64.TryParse(entry, out value)).
                          Select(entry=> Convert.ToInt64(entry)).ToList<long>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just loop through, no need for linq

```
bool allParsed = true;
List<long> longList = new List<long>();
foreach(object s in TheArrayList)
{
    long val;
    if(Int64.TryParse(s, out val))
        longList.Add(val);
    else
    {
        allParsed = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(!allParsed)
    // handle the error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the deferred nature of LINQ to Objects:

```
long value = 0;
var result = TheArrayList.Where(m => long.TryParse(m, out value))
                         .Select(x => value);
```

This works, but it is problematic in other ways:

1. It will break if you want to convert that code to PLINQ.
2. It will break if `TheArrayList` is actually some IQueryable going to a database.
3. It looks like it's buggy

Comment: It actually says that ArrayList doesn't contain a definition for Where.

Comment: @frenchie: If `TheArrayList` is a non-generic list, simply put a `Cast<object>()` before the `Where`.